# Matlab authenticate FTP with private key file

Tags: matlab, ssl, ftp

We can use Matlab's built in ftp function to authenticate to the [FTP](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ftp.html) server as follows:

```
HOST = 'a.b.c.d';
USER = 'hello';
PASS = 'world';

conn = ftp(HOST, USER, PASS);
```

However, I have now a FTP server where the authentication goes through a private key file (generated by [PuTTY](https://www.putty.org/)). How can I use this in this context to Authenticate? Using FileZilla you can select the Logon Type "Key File" (I tested and this worked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found a file exchange package that allowed you to use a private key to authenticate to the SFTP.

See [Secure FTP (SSH/SFTP/SCP)](https://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2016/04/15/secure-ftp-sshsftpscp/).

However, I am open to hear about other solutions (e.g. by Matlab) if they exist.